# How can I reference a project without linking to it in a csproj?

Tags: c#, msbuild, mstest, csproj

I have a test project that runs a program (a `.exe`) and ensures that the results come out as expected.

I'd like to declare that the test project depends on the project that builds the `.exe`, and place the `.exe` drop into a subdirectory of `$(OutDir)` (or `$(OutputPath)`).

- `$(OutDir)MyTests.dll` (test project)
- `$(OutDir)\Product\Foo.exe` (tested project)
- `$(OutDir)\Product\xxx.dll` (dependencies of the tested project)

This way I can write a test of the form:

```
[TestClass]
[DeploymentItem("Product", "Product")]
public class RunFoo
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void HelpTextMatches()
    {
        // System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Product\foo.exe" ...)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to declare something like a `<ProjectReference` in my test `.csproj` file which will allow me to achieve this?

(I don't want to just have a `<Copy` task grabbing the outputs of the program under test because then there's nothing to force MSBuild to build the program under test before the test project.)

Comment: What's wrong with `ProjectReference`? provided your test project is just a test class, its awareness of the project under test is valid.

Comment: @KMoraz: That causes the output of that project to be declared as an assembly reference, which is not appropriate here. I want to test the product as it would be deployed -- `ProjectReference` would hide bugs whereby the test project deploys binaries on which the product depends (but which the product didn't itself copy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand your reasons for not using `ProjectReference`, but this essentially does what adding `ProjectReference` does except without the added assembly references.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ExtraDependencies include="ExeProject.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="GetExtraDependenciesTargets">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ExtraDependencies)" Targets="GetTargetPath">
        <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="ResolvedDependencyTargets" />
    </MSBuild>
</Target>

<Target Name="BuildExtraDependencies"
        BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"
        DependsOnTargets="GetExtraDependenciesTargets"
        Inputs="@(ExtraDependencies)"
        Outputs="@(ResolvedDependencyTargets)">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ExtraDependencies)" Targets="Build">
        <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="BuiltDependencyTargets" />
    </MSBuild>
</Target>
```

Alternatively, you could keep the `ProjectReference` but just hijack the build process right after the `ResolveProjectReferences` target and remove the exe as a dependency (from `_ResolvedProjectReferencePaths`).

Comment: Unfortunately this causes the product to be built twice :/ This is better than nothing though.

Comment: @BillyONeal edited to a version that doesn't allow building twice. Hope it helps, whatever the reasons for not using ProjectReference are.

Comment: +1 :) I would use ProjectReference, but I don't want the test code to be able to reference product types directly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in SDK-style projects.

Comment: (Build log says "Skipping target "BuildExtraDependencies" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.")

Answer (score 9):

> I'd like to declare that the test project depends on the project that builds the .exe...

Set `ReferenceOutputAssembly` to `false` on the project reference ([source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2015/04/04/how-to-have-a-project-reference-without-referencing-the-actual-binary/)):

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj">
  <Project>{b402782f-de0a-41fa-b364-60612a786fb2}</Project>
  <Name>ProjectA</Name>
  <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
</ProjectReference>
```

> ...and place the .exe drop into a subdirectory of $(OutDir) (or $(OutputPath))

Post-build action.  Or just run the exe under test in-place.

Comment: Is there a way to get the OutDir of the referenced project to make it easier to copy in a  post-build action?

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can do that using a "copy" task (maybe invoked in a *post-build* condition of your project).

Please consider that you can control the build order in Visual Studio simply using `Project -> Project build order`. Visual Studio shows a dialog for allowing you to explicitly set projects dependencies: if you set that your `Test` project depends on your `Foo` project than `Foo` is being build before `Test` (you can check it moving to tab "Build order" in the same Visual Studio dialog).

Comment: Project build order (as you describe above) is not available to msbuild. It requires building using a solution file, which isn't an option for me.